# Selenium fails to click

Tags: java, selenium

```
selenium.click([xpath to object])
```

Selenium click method seems to be screwed up for me. It recognises the button I want to click and thinks it clicks it. But nothing happens on the screen. The next line involves clicking another button on the next screen. It fails because it cant locate the button because the first click hasn't actually happened.

[EDIT]
It looks like It just fails to click after the screen changes. It will click the log in button fine, and load the new screen. The next click fails, but if i give it a gentle push(IE click the button for it) all the followin clicks in the script run fine. So it seems to be a problem with a click after a screen change?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code for the button and the code/locator you are using to perform the click.

Comment: did you figure out what was wrong, without clicking it yourself?

Comment: @oma, It seems in the end it was just an error with loading. I added a delay and all was right with the world once again :)

Comment: ok, thx! btw the source of my problem was mootools js lib. It's wasn't best friends with selenium. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6996141/252799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and this code worked for me:

```
    mouseOver(locator);
    mouseDownAt(locator, "10,10");
    mouseUpAt(locator, "10,10");
```

I wrapped it up in a clickButton() method and use it instead of click()

Comment: But doesnt this highly depend on the screen resolution?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked. It still thinks it worked, but the screen never transitions. It continues and looks for the next object, and fails because the page hasn't transitioned

Comment: Does it transition eventually or does it just hang?

Comment: It was just trying to click to soon after all, I put in a delay and its all happy now :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("button"));    
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;    
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Since you are not able to use selenium click method you can try to click on the button by using javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it on Internet Explorer, there is a known bug that its window must be foremost. Some people get past this with doing another event which makes the window get focus like clicking twice or maximising, etc. etc.