# capybara finds button but clicking it does nothing

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

UPDATE: I removed most javascript dependencies and it worked. Don't know what library or code is the evil part, I needed none of it.

---

simple form, two input fields and a button

```
fill_in 'cellNumber', :with => '13245678'
fill_in 'password', :with => 'mypass'
click_button('OK')
```

It finds the button, but nothing happens.

Important!, if I click the myself, everything works as expected.

```
   <button type="submit" id="loginid">OK</button>
</form>
```

Using ruby-debug, I find that find_button("OK").click returns "". If not found would  raise error.
If I click manually inside the firefox window, halting the capybara test with sleep or in debug, I see (test window in focus) a blue frame has appeared around the button , as it's been selected somehow.

Anyway, I'm close to checking in to a mental facility right now... Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm running into a situation where a button with type != button causes Cappy to fail in a really odd way (missing resources). Switching to type=button fixes all problems. Maybe related?

Comment: mootools dependency was the issue, see the answer.

Comment: My problem ended up being something different. A button was posting to a non-existent resource, reloading the page and causing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript may interfere**. The page had some unnecessary dependencies to Squeezebox, Mootools-1.2.5 and Function.cbb.js, so I just removed them and refactored to use more css functionality (like hover) and specialized js. I'm not impressed with this. Nonetheless, I hope this answer would help others.

update: Seems like **Mootools** is **incompatible** with **Selenium**. Without including any other JS library/code than the mootools core library, it breaks. I've tried both 1.2.5-core and 1.3.2-full-compact.

Comment: Is there a bug report somewhere that tracks this behavior? Is it even considered a bug?